Is there a mel command for enabling 'Multi Component Mode'
The default function is to toggle between Object and Multi component mode, I would like to directly trigger both of these commands, rather than a toggle.
I think I have figured out how to trigger object mode, using selectMode :
selectMode -h;

But I was not able to figure out to trigger multi component, similar to the button on the modelling toolkit or the toggle hotkey. I tried a bunch of the lines the script editor spat out but no luck.
My goal is assign both functions to their own hotkey.
Is this possible?

From the documentation https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2025/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/ it's simply selectMode -object and selectMode -component. How is your question related to Python and what problem did you have beyond the documentation?

@Grismar, selectMode -object appears to work but selectMode -component does not. The script editor does not print out anything when I run selectMode -component.  The script editor prints out nothing usefull in either case. I tagged python, because I was also open to the python equivalent of Mel, I removed the Python tag now.

I'm not sufficiently familiar with Maya, but could it be that the specific type of document/project you're working in doesn't allow the switch because it somehow doesn't work for it? Have you tried it in other contexts, on a plain project?
